# Why is a jquery toggle working on the customizer preview but not live in wordpress / woocommerce

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, toggle

I want to implement a showmore jquery element to my woocommerce page, but it doesn´t show up on the normal version of the site. It shows only on the customizer preview and works well, there.

I´ve tested a lot of different jquery toggle codes and it´s always the same... I have no caching, could it be some kind of javascript problem of the theme? I don´t get why it makes a difference in the customizer preview...

This is my code, that works in the customizer version, but not in the normal one:

```
<style>
    .addReadMore.showlesscontent .SecSec,
    .addReadMore.showlesscontent .readLess {
        display: none;
    }

    .addReadMore.showmorecontent .readMore {
        display: none;
    }

    .addReadMore .readMore,
    .addReadMore .readLess {
        font-weight: bold;
        margin-left: 2px;
        color: blue;
        cursor: pointer;
    }

    .addReadMoreWrapTxt.showmorecontent .SecSec,
    .addReadMoreWrapTxt.showmorecontent .readLess {
        display: block;
    }
</style>
```

```
<script>

function AddReadMore() {
    //This limit you can set after how much characters you want to show Read More.
    var carLmt = 280;
    // Text to show when text is collapsed
    var readMoreTxt = " ... Read More";
    // Text to show when text is expanded
    var readLessTxt = " Read Less";


    //Traverse all selectors with this class and manupulate HTML part to show Read More
    $(".addReadMore").each(function() {
        if ($(this).find(".firstSec").length)
            return;

        var allstr = $(this).text();
        if (allstr.length > carLmt) {
            var firstSet = allstr.substring(0, carLmt);
            var secdHalf = allstr.substring(carLmt, allstr.length);
            var strtoadd = firstSet + "<span class='SecSec'>" + secdHalf + "</span><span class='readMore'  title='Click to Show More'>" + readMoreTxt + "</span><span class='readLess' title='Click to Show Less'>" + readLessTxt + "</span>";
            $(this).html(strtoadd);
        }

    });
    //Read More and Read Less Click Event binding
    $(document).on("click", ".readMore,.readLess", function() {
        $(this).closest(".addReadMore").toggleClass("showlesscontent showmorecontent");
    });
}
$(function() {
    //Calling function after Page Load
    AddReadMore();
});

</script>
```

```
<p class="addReadMore showlesscontent">Es ist ein lang erwiesener Fakt, dass ein Leser vom Text abgelenkt wird, wenn er sich ein Layout ansieht. Der Punkt, Lorem Ipsum zu nutzen, ist, dass es mehr oder weniger die normale Anordnung von Buchstaben darstellt und somit nach lesbarer Sprache aussieht. Viele Desktop Publisher und Webeditoren nutzen mittlerweile Lorem Ipsum als den Standardtext, auch die Suche im Internet nach "lorem ipsum" macht viele Webseiten sichtbar, wo diese noch immer vorkommen. Mittlerweile gibt es mehrere Versionen des Lorem Ipsum, einige zufällig, andere bewusst (beeinflusst von Witz und des eigenen Geschmacks)Es ist ein lang erwiesener Fakt, dass ein Leser vom Text abgelenkt wird, wenn er sich ein Layout ansieht. Der Punkt, Lorem Ipsum zu nutzen, ist, dass es mehr oder weniger die normale Anordnung von Buchstaben darstellt und somit nach lesbarer Sprache aussieht. Viele Desktop Publisher und Webeditoren nutzen mittlerweile Lorem Ipsum als den Standardtext, auch die</p>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok found the solution: The $ was the problem... replaced it with jquery.

A classic wordpress problem with jquery!

```
<script>
function AddReadMore() {
    var carLmt = 280;
    var readMoreTxt = " ... Read More";
    var readLessTxt = " Read Less";
    jquery(".addReadMore").each(function() {
        if (jquery(this).find(".firstSec").length)
            return;
        var allstr = jquery(this).text();
        if (allstr.length > carLmt) {
            var firstSet = allstr.substring(0, carLmt);
            var secdHalf = allstr.substring(carLmt, allstr.length);
            var strtoadd = firstSet + "<span class='SecSec'>" + secdHalf + "</span><span class='readMore'  title='Click to Show More'>" + readMoreTxt + "</span><span class='readLess' title='Click to Show Less'>" + readLessTxt + "</span>";
            jquery(this).html(strtoadd);
        }
    });
    jquery(document).on("click", ".readMore,.readLess", function() {
        jquery(this).closest(".addReadMore").toggleClass("showlesscontent showmorecontent");
    });
}
jquery(function() {
    AddReadMore();
});
</script>
```